# Flutter Cached network image

Tags: flutter, caching

i have a question about cached_network_image in flutter, i have about 500 images in the firebase storage, i used their urls and put all of them in my app so that i can display all the images, but the more people will access the images the more bandwidth will be consumed between the user and firebase, so i decided to use cached_network_image so that if the user access an image, it will be cached then the second time the image will be loaded from the device not from the firebase anymore

`CachedNetworkImage( imageUrl: 'url', placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(), errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error), ),`

my question is, if the user closed the app or he turned off his phone or restart it, will the image still be cached ? or it will be cleared ? and if so, what is the best way or option to make the image be cached forever until the user by himself clear it?

Answer (score 2):

Actually no, but temporary memory files can be deleted when the application size increases or an error is encountered. This can also be done automatically when the data stored by the application increases.

Data is usually deleted when the application is removed from the device memory.